# Add product short description between title and price lines

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can I add short description in this code after title and before price:

```
$output .= '<div class="desc">';
                            $output .= '<h4><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h4>';
if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) $output .= '<span class="price">'. $price_html .'</span>';
                        $output .= '</div>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your own code? I don't know for sure what happens with $output in the end but if it is just put out you most likely only have to add something like $output .= "<div>your description here ...</div>"; after the second line of this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the dedicated WordPress **`get_the_excerpt()`** function:

```
$output .= '<div class="desc">
    <h4><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h4>
    <p>'. get_the_excerpt() .'</p>';
if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) $output .= '<span class="price">'. $price_html .'</span>';
                        $output .= '</div>';

                    $output .= '</div>';
```

This should work